# iptables for traffic monitoring

Tags: iptables

I have rules like this in my IPTABLES:

-A INPUT -s 166.100.102.50/32 -j LOG --log-level 7

and I wrote a script that grabs the output of these rules and outputs the bytes from the IP to my server.

I was hoping to get suggestions on how I could create a rules that tracks ip traffic from dispersant subnets. The ip address aren't fixed and even the subnets aren't fixed. For example:

120.2.33.45 could be the ip address of the device one day and 204.65.3.88 could be the ip address of the same device the next day.

I think that if there was a way to write the rule so that it gave me the ip address of everything except a range of ip address that are fixed, like 166.100.102.50 then I would be ok.

Something like:

-A INPUT -s **NOT EQUAL** 166.100.102.50/32 -j LOG --log-level 7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you want (watch the `!`):

```
iptables -A INPUT ! -s 166.100.102.50/32 -j LOG --log-level 7
```

This will match everything with source address NOT 166.100.102.50.

From `man iptables`

```
   [!] -s, --source address[/mask][,...]
          Source specification. Address can be either a  network  name,  a
          hostname,  a  network  IP  address  (with  /mask), or a plain IP
          address. Hostnames will be resolved once only, before  the  rule
          is  submitted  to  the  kernel.  Please note that specifying any
          name to be resolved with a remote query such as DNS is a  really
          bad idea.  The mask can be either a network mask or a plain num‐
          ber, specifying the number of 1's at the left side of  the  net‐
          work  mask.   Thus, a mask of 24 is equivalent to 255.255.255.0.
```

Here starts the relevant part:

```
          A "!" argument before  the  address  specification  inverts  the
          sense  of  the  address.  The  flag  --src  is an alias for this
          option.  Multiple addresses can  be  specified,  but  this  will
          expand  to  multiple  rules (when adding with -A), or will cause
          multiple rules to be deleted (with -D).
```

Comment: Thanks, can you do the ! statement for a range of address too?

Comment: Yes. Just write the rule, and `!` will negate it (so all IPs except those in range).

Comment: for example (166.100.102.50/32 206.1.121.32/32) etc

Comment: Intrapositioned negation is deprecated (meaning the ! *after* an option switch. The way to go is " ... -A INPUT ! -s 166.100. ..."

Comment: Also, negation is "not allowed with multiple source or destination IP addresses". So you can specify ONE host or ONE subnet per rule, but not several addresses/subnets like he mentions in the comment above. You must use several rules here.

Comment: You can use subnets as a "range" (1.2.3.0/24 for example), but not different ranges.

Comment: can I define an IPSET with diferent IP's in it and negate the IPSET?

Comment: Sure, mulaz. I refer to his comment where he wants to use different subnets in the same rule. This is not possible.

Comment: can I do something like, ipset -N test host 166.100.102.50/32 host 206.1.121.32/32  and then negate the ipset in the rule ?

Comment: @KarmaFusebox edited the -s ! -> ! -s

Answer (score 4):

You may find that building a chain here will make things a lot easier to work with.

A chain is basically like a sub-table.  You send stuff to it, and then you can either return or process things within that chain.

```
-t INPUT -N LOGME
# return stuff, that we don't want to handle
-A LOGME -s 166.100.102.50/32 -j RETURN
-A LOGME -s 192.168.27.0/24 -j RETURN
# log everything that hasn't been returned
-A LOGME -j LOG --log-level 7
```

Another option, might be to create and use an [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html), which basically lets you build a set of addresses, which you can then reference in a rule using the `--match-set` option.

Comment: can I do something like, ipset -N test host 166.100.102.50/32 host 206.1.121.32/32 and then negate the ipset in the rule ?